# Implementing a Critical Section in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, guid, critical-section, tempdata

I came across this scenario when I had to backup some data in tempdata and reuse it in subsequent views and wizards in asp.net mvc3.

As TempData being a Dictionary, I had to use the key value pair, to avoid confusion and mess, I just used GUID as the key and the required models are backed up as values and pass the generated key as key in URL to fetch back the backed up data in next step.

The problem / downside of this is that, **GUID is 36 characters** in length. This makes the URL real big. I believe all that I need is uniqueness to certain extend and `DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("X")` will give a key which is unique and never has a chance to repeat and it is relatively small with **15 characters**.

However even if I implement that, the probability of getting absolute uniqueness is not 0 as there could be simultaneous request accessing this at the same point of time.  So, I need a critical section kind of setup.